# Generic lists in array list

Tags: c#, arrays, list, arraylist, generic-list

There is a array list that contain generic lists. How can i access the variables that in generic list? But i want to access the variables via the array list.

```
ArrayList TheList = new ArrayList();

List<NewType>[] GenericLists = new List<NewType>[4];

GenericLists[0].Add(variable);
       .
       . 
       .
       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                TheList.Add(GenericLists[i]);
            }
```

How can i print the variables via the Array list?

Comment: As a general rule, it's a bad idea to mix and match arrays and collections.

Comment: You have an array *of* lists, not an "array list", nor an `ArrayList`.

Comment: This is a part of my project. So i have to mix.

Comment: Why not just use a `List<List<NewType>>`?  Then you won't have to cast the items.

Comment: i have 4 generic lists and i should to put this generic lists in an array list. And i should to use the array list while i'm printing.

Comment: You should also never use `ArrayList`. There is *always* a better solution than htat.

Comment: You can use at least `List<IList>`...

Answer (score 4):

You need to iterate over the items of your `ArrayList` and cast each item to `List<NewType>` then you can iterate over the items in the lists and display them or whatever you want...

```
foreach(var list in TheList)
{
   var currentList = (List<NewType>)list;
   ...
}
```

Or you can use Linq methods to cast them:

```
foreach(var list in TheList.Cast<NewList>())
```

These assumes that all items in the array list are of type `NewList`. Otherwise you will get an `InvalidCastException` at runtime. To avoid this you can use [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) or [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) operators to check if the type is `NewList`, or you can use `OfType` method which does this for you:

```
foreach(var list in TheList.OfType<NewList>())
```

Comment: Probably a good idea to mention type checking since we're iterating an `ArrayList` here...

Comment: This is a good answer. But I do think it's worth reiterating the points made by D Stanley and Bradley that if at all possible, the original code should simply be changed so that it's not using `ArrayList` in the first place. A `List<List<T>>` would be more appropriate here. Maybe the OP will take it more seriously if it's in the answer. :)